# Are TCP Packets Received when Requested

Tags: windows, tcp, wireshark

I have a server process running that listens on a port. I can establish the connection with this port, but when I try to send data, the client reports that data has been sent, while the server never receives it.

I am using WireShark to trace the data, and I can't find the data packet I sent, which means it was never received. So here's my question. Does this mean that:

1. The packet has never reached the network adapter on the server side?
   or,
2. The server process never called the receiving API (recv() or equivalent)?

In other words, are TCP packets transmitted only when the receiving side calls the receiving API, or are they transmitted automatically whenever they are sent, and the receiving API only reads the buffered data?

Comment: TCP segments are not requested. It has nothing to do with `recv()` if it didn't arrive in Wireshark at the receiver it never got to any local NIC.

Comment: Paste the server client code. Check firewall rules as well

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thank you. This answers my question. :)

Comment: @VijaySB Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server code. Firewalls are deactivated.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Could you re-write that comment as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?